# Use ArrayList or List in method parameter list

Tags: java, list, methods, arraylist, parameters

Hi I am wondering if it is better to use list or arrayList as a method parameter?

for example -

```
public static void calculate(List<T> list) {}
```

or

```
public static void calculate(ArrayList<T> list) {}
```

I was thinking that it was better to use List because it gives you more options to use a linked list or whatever... but if I am wrong could you tell me why ArrayList is better or why List is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to interfaces, code to interfaces, code to interfaces.

What if someone wanted to use your API but pass a different sort of List?  Or even not a list at all, but a Collection?  Use the most generic interface your API requires.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should accept any argument that the method makes sense for.

If your method makes sense for any `List`, the argument should have type `List<?>`.

If your method doesn't need to access the items by index, it might be a good idea to allow the method to accept a `Collection<?>` or an `Iterable<?>`.

If your method only makes sense for lists of numbers, the argument should have type `List<? extends Number>`.

In general, it is not a good idea for a parameter to have type `ArrayList`. If your method only makes sense for certain types of `List`, such as `List`s that are mutable, or `List`s that accept `null` items, you should make the argument have type `List<?>` but carefully document the requirements.